# NOT IN key word not working following mysql query ?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

mysql Query

```
SELECT FileId FROM PersonalDetail WHERE NOT IN (SELECT FileId FROM FamilyDetail)
```

I got this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3
```

I have 2 db tables 
 1.PersonalDetail-FileId -pk
 2.FamilyDetail-FileId-fk

I want FileId from PersonalDetail table  not in the FamilyDetail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing **field** name

pass *field_name* **(column name)** in which you find something.

```
SELECT FileId FROM PersonalDetail WHERE field_name NOT IN (SELECT FileId FROM FamilyDetail)
```

Comment: oops Ohhhhh, I spends lots of time for that but didn't see that small mistake , Thank a lots @Devsi Odedra

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` instead :

```
select p.*
from PersonalDetail p
where not exists (select 1 from FamilyDetail f where f.FileId = p.FileId);
```

For your current attempt you have not specified the column name in outer query after `WHERE` clause

It should be

```
. . .
WHERE column_name not in ( . . .)
```

Comment: This Query also give same result @Yogesh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Careful with `NOT IN` because `FamilyDetail.FileId` can be **NULL**. In that case `NOT IN` will always return **FALSE** because `NOT IN` is treated as `<>`, which compares all rows from the subquery like `PersonalDetail.FileId <> FamilyDetail.FileId`, which fails when comparing with **NULL**: `FamilyDetail.FileId <> NULL` will not result in **TRUE**.

Better to use like:

```
SELECT FileId FROM PersonalDetail 
WHERE FileId NOT IN 
(SELECT FileId FROM FamilyDetail WHERE FileId IS NOT NULL);
```